# Remove same modifier from many objects

Tags: modifiers

I have been searching on Internet for a while and I only have found this piece of code (from this site)

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
for o in scene.objects:
    if o.type == 'MESH':
    for m in o.modifiers:
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Smoke")
```

But it didn´t work for me. It only removes the modifier from the active object, not for all the objects in the scene.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks pals.

Answer (score 6):

Many operators work on only the active object and some will work on all selected objects, removing a modifier is a case of only working on the active object, the active object is the one that has it's properties displayed so is the only one with a visible modifier list.

You can delete modifiers without using operators, this way you don't have to change the active object and it also doesn't matter if the modifier has been renamed.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
for o in scene.objects:
    if o.type == 'MESH':
        for m in o.modifiers:
            if m.type == 'SMOKE':
                o.modifiers.remove(m)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following only addresses the case where it is desired all objects in a specific set to have the same modifier. It does not address the case where deleting one or all instances of a specific type of modifier, i.e. "Smoke", from a set of objects which may have completely different sets and permutations of modifiers.

1. Enable the Copy Attributes Add-on.
   [image: Where to find the Copy Attributes Add-on in Blender User Preferences]

   2. Remove all or specific modifiers from one of the objects.
   3. Select all objects you want to remove the modifiers from, with the one without modifiers being the last (active).
   4. Ctrl+C, "Copy Modifiers"

Comment: You can do this directly with the `Ctrl`+`L`menu *Link > Modifiers* no addons needed

Answer (score 1):

try setting every mesh object as active one by one

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
for o in scene.objects:
    if o.type == 'MESH':
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = o
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Smoke")
```